# Fancybox iframe doesn't always work. :(

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I am fancybox (1) to display pop up overlays with iframes in them. It functions where I click on the anchor and instead of a going the page the fancybox script overwrites the command and forces the iframe pop up.

```
<a href="iframe.html" class="fancybox.iframe">click here</a>
```

What happenes occasionally is that a user will click the link but the browser will go to the iframed link and no pop up.

Is there any way to make the the element a div instead of an anchor and give it a URL attribute that fancybox recognizes so there is no visiting the iframed page?

Answer (score 0):

For fancybox v1.3.x you shouldn't use `class="fancybox.iframe"` but `class="iframe"` or set `"type":"iframe"` option within your custom script like:

```
$(".iframe").fancybox({
 "type":"iframe",
 "width": 620, //or whatever value you prefer
 "height": 320
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about Fancybox v.2.0.6?

this is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>


<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.....etc></a>

...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox();

});
</script>

</body>
```

thank you!